# How to copy excel sheet to another workbook with same format using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have to copy the excel sheets from different source files to destination sheets with same format(Headers, Borders, Fonts, Formulas, Background color, Spacing, ... etc)

I have tried below script but it is copying only data also, header is not exactly matched.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(src, sheet_name="Sheet1")

df.to_excel(des, sheet_name='new_tab')
```

Any help is appreciated. Preferable Python.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible with pandas. You should probably have a look at VBA and write a macro for it, though i can say writing vba is not fun at all compared to python.